# Accessing user attributes (name, avatar, etc) in view with polymorphic commentable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

So a polymorphic relationship that has comments on articles and newsitems, and each comment also belongs to a user. I've made it work so far, it seems, and in the view, this works for printing out the user_id for each comment posted:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div>
    <%= comment.updated_at.strftime("%b %d %Y, %H:%M") %></strong>
  </div>

  <div>
  <%= comment.user_id %>
  </div>

  <div>
  <%= comment.comment %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But obviously I'll need to add username/avatar/etc, not the id. How do I access those values?

**UPDATE**: following mudasobwa's answer.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

…and…

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Adding `<%= comment.user.email %>` to the view after that produces:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

UPDATE 2: And in the view, this prints what it is supposed to:

```
<%= comment.user_id %> | <%= comment.commentable_id %> | <%= comment.commentable_type %>
```

Comment: As soon as your model specifies relations like `has_one :user` in `Comment`, you can just use `comment.user.name`.

Comment: Have updated with the models for you.

Comment: @MatthewBennett To confirm, you're able to retrieve `comment.user_id` but not `comment.user`?

Comment: That seems to be the case, Fan Jin. "Comments" has a 'user_id' column, so perhaps it is getting it from there. 'email' would be in the 'Users' table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comment.user` `comment.user.email`etc. work, as suggested by zetetic in the comments to his answer. It was the nil returns. I was testing it on pages that had other comments created before changing the model, so they didn't have the user attributes assigned to the comments, so Rails was returning nil, leading to the confusion. Removing those comments and posting new ones correctly displays the user's email and username next to the comment on the article page now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving through a polymorphic association, get the associated object using the association name, e.g.:

```
comment.commentable
```

Rails will automagically instantiate the class according to the `commentable_type`:

```
comment.commentable.class # => User
```

Comment: So it would be `comment.commentable.user.email` ?

Comment: No, just `comment.commentable.email`. The `commentable` *is* the user.

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns `undefined method 'email' for #<Newsitem:0x007ff822c9e268>`. In comments index it lets me do `<%= comment.commentable_type %>` but returns `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` for `<%= comment.commentable.email %>`. On the admin/users page I can get a list of users and print e-mails with `<%= user.email %>`.

Comment: *undefined method 'email' for #<Newsitem:0x007ff822c9e268>*

means the commentable is a Newitem, not a user. Newsitem apparently does not respond to ':email'. Your code needs to filter out the items that are not Users before trying to render the comments, or branch on the `commentable_type` or `commentable.class` and handle each item appropriately.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, in theory it is a comment on a newsitem by a user. User is not commentable, but has_many comments which belong_to that user. In theory. I am trying to print the email/name of the user next to his comments below each newsitem/article.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Do you have rows in the comments table with a commentable_type==User? What is the result of `Comment.pluck(:commentable_type).uniq`

Comment: On the comments index page, the commentable_type is either Article or Newsitem. Beside each comment on either type of page I can print out the user_id of the person who made the comment, I just can't work out how to access his email/name/avatar/etc.

Comment: So you get to the user by `comment.user`, thus `comment.user.email`. Your original issue is *not* related to polymorphism, you simply have a comment  with a user_id of nil.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have a has_many/belongs_to relationship working fine with another part of the app, and it works as you say. On that one a newsitem can belong_to an article, which has_many newsitems (updates). Then `@newsitem.article` or `@newsitem.article.headline` works fine, on the newsitem page, or `<% @article.newsitems.each do |newsitem| %>`, etc. on the article page. With this problem, I'm on the Newsitem page, which has_many comments, and I'm trying to pull in the user email/name. It's late here, I'll sleep on it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do I perhaps need to use "has_many through" to make this work? As in: a "user has_many articles through comments" or "comments through articles", to then be able to access user info on article pages?

Comment: Doubtful. The error message implies that `comment.user` returns `nil`. That is the source of the problem. If you can pinpoint the comment that triggers the error, you should be able to load up that record in the console and see what's gong on.

Comment: Aaaarrgh, I can't believe I was that stupid. Of course, the nil returns. I was testing it on pages that had other comments created before changing the model, so they didn't have the user attributes assigned to the comments. Thanks for the nudges.